# Drupal 8 Webform add prefix to uploaded file names

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

I have a webform with a file upload field.  I need do one of two things.  Either upload files into a subfolder inside the private area, OR, add a prefix to the filename that the user is uploading.   The user can upload several files.  The webform editor allows you to 'Rename' the file and use tokens for this, but I don't see any way of preserving the original file name.   I can hack  getFileDestinationUri() in WebformManagedFileBase.php to do what I want, but obviously I would rather not do that.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can use the drupal form alter hook to alter the destination.  I had thought of this but felt if was unlikely to work.  It does.

Below is MY code solution: (I may be missing container types)

```
function _mymodule_fix_elements(&$elements) {
  foreach ($elements as $key => &$element) {
    if (strpos($key, '#') !== 0) {
      if (is_array($element)) {
        if (isset($element['#type'])) {
          if (($element['#type'] == 'fieldset') ||
              ($element['#type'] == 'webform_flexbox') ||
              ($element['#type'] == 'container')) {
            _mymodule_fix_elements($element);
          } else if ($element['#type'] == 'managed_file') {
            $pattern = $element['#upload_location'];
            if (strpos($pattern, 'private:') === 0) {
              $element['#upload_location'] = $pattern . '/' . $key;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $id) {
  if (strpos($id, 'webform_') === 0) {
    _mymodule_fix_elements($form['elements']);
  }
}
```